# Search model that has_and_belongs_to_many :tags

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, has-and-belongs-to-many

I need a little help with Rails. I am transferring a backend system of data look up services from PHP to RoR. Which I am finding to be surprisingly concise.

I need to be able to search a model on its relation with a tag model. Each model has been given the has_and_belongs_to_many association.

When the search is passed in with a comma separated list of values I need to perform an 'AND' search on the tags so I can find all resources that have all tags passed (i.e. London AND bridges).

Also it needs to be case insensitive. Currently I have only a single tag search being performed in the Resource model.

```rb
def self.search(search)
    where('LOWER(tags.name) = ?', search.downcase).joins(:tags)
end
```

All my attempts at using an array using either `where`, `find`, or `all` have not been successful.

The PHP way of doing an AND search on a join table seemed rather hacky, I am hoping Rails can provide a more elegant solution.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Maybe give a try for acts_as_taggable_on - gem which provides a lot of nifty helpers. Thanks to this gem you will save a lot of time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you need an `AND`, then you need to ensure that the number of matching tags is precisely the number you requested, so that involves a `COUNT` as well. The query you're gunning for will involve `IN`.

It would be more convenient if you could ensure that your tags are always stored in lower case. Doing operations like `LOWER(...)` in a query is going to be trouble if you have a lot of data since it results in an automatic table scan and cannot be indexed.

Secondly, I'd avoid using `has_and_belongs_to_many` as this is a relic from the Rails 1.0 days that isn't as flexible or reliable as the `has_many :through` alternative. The only difference between the two approaches from a database perspective is that the `:through` join table has a unique ID for each entry and is represented by a first-class model. The `has_and_belongs_to_many` system is quirky to the point of uselessness a lot of the time.

What you're probably wanting is something that looks like this:

```
def self.with_all_tags(*tags)
  tags = tags.flatten.collect(&:downcase)
  where('tags.name IN (?)', tags).having('COUNT(tags.id)=?', tags.length).joins(:tags)
end

def self.with_any_tags(*tags)
  tags = tags.flatten.collect(&:downcase)
  where('tags.name IN (?)', tags).joins(:tags)
end
```

You may need to experiment to get the right behaviour. Your example wasn't that specific.

Comment: What I was hoping to explain is that if the string "London,bridges" is passed as the search terms, all resources that have both "London" and "bridges" tags would be returned. They must have both in order to be returned.

Comment: In that case you need `WHERE tags.name IN ('london', 'bridges')` with `HAVING COUNT(tags.id)=2` to ensure both are matched. This might require a `GROUP BY main_model.id` where that's whatever your main model's table name is.

Comment: Thanks, this is the same way I did it in PHP, but it ended up being much more verbose. I just needed a little direction to accomplish it in RoR